# When I run a file in debug in Pycharm it automatically commits the file, how can I disable this?

Tags: pycharm

When I am trying to debug multiple files in pycharm, it is automatically committing and pushing to my repository, I am assuming there is a settings that has been changed, but I have not changed any settings. This started happening a few hours ago.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add some preparation script in your run settings? These are executed also if you debug. Or some plugin. You can go to the main setting window, and just search about `commit`. It should show you the relevant setting (if it is something project or global).

Comment: I'll check into that next time, just reset pycharm to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just reset pycharm settings by going to preferences -> manage settings -> reset to default settings & restart.